# Inline CSS SVG from URL is not displaying

Tags: html, css, svg

I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs34f9FiHps&t=16m) about CSS stuff. I am trying to recreate the "marching ants" border effect, but to no avail. I'm using `Firefox 95.0.1` and `Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110`, which should have SVG support. I don't care about IE, because this is just a learning exercise, so I can play around with it.

I am using Sass `^7.0.1` (SCSS). Other CSS effects display, though, and change when modified.

```css
//style.css
.item{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: brown;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cstyle%3E@keyframes marching-ants%7Bto%7Bstroke-dashoffset: -15px;%7D%7D%3C/style%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25';style='stroke: black;stroke-width: 4px;fill: none;stroke-dasharray: 10px 5px;animation: marching-ants 1s infinite 4s linear;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        }

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<--!standard headers-->
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item">Item 1</li>
      <li class="item">Item 2</li>
      <li class="item">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have also tried without encoding, and with `background-image` and it didn't work. Other CSS effects do work, so I know it's not an organization issue.

This is the encoded URL, I also broke it up so it's easier to read:

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml,\
<svg xmlns="http://www3.org/2000/svg">\
<style>@keyframes marching-ants{to{stroke-dashoffset: -15px;}}</style>\
<rect width="100%" height="100%";style="stroke: black;stroke-width: 4px;fill: none;\
stroke-dasharray: 10px 5px; animation: marching-ants 1s infinite 4s linear;"/>\
</svg>');
}
```

Comment: Your svg is incorrect Copy paste the code in the quotes in your browser addressbar

Comment: SVG is not even loading when searching URL. Fix that, you should be fine.

Comment: Is it something obvious, because I cannot find anything out of place. I pasted an encoded version, and everything looks right.

Comment: Look at this: `<rect width="100%" height="100%";style="..."` - The semicolon should be exchanged for a space.

Comment: Oh my god. I guess look at it for so long I couldn't see anything anymore. Thank you for your eyes.